# Preventing MySQL insert if a row already contains INSERT data

Tags: mysql, insert, key, duplicates

Having a bit of a problem. Firstly, here's my table structure.

Table doc_perms

```
id    user_id    doc_id   can_view    can_edit    can_delete
```

ID being the PK and user_id and doc_id being FK's of other tables.

Basically, what I need is to prevent an INSERT query from executing if the INSERT data for user_id and doc_id already exists in a row regardless of the rest of the columns.

For example

if you have the data

```
user_id  doc_id
   1        1
   1        2
```

And then you try do an INSERT with user_id = 1 and doc_id = 2, the query fails because there's already a row with that data in it.

Hope this makes sense.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates in `doc_perms`, you can [create a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on `(user_id, doc_id)`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX doc_perms_index 
  ON doc_perms (user_id,doc_id)
```

If there are duplicates, you can use [ALTER IGNORE ... ADD UNIQUE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) will remove them:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE doc_perms 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX doc_perms_index (user_id, doc_id)
```

(Among all rows that share the same (user_id, doc_id), all the rows except one will be dropped. The row that is kept is unspecified.)

After you create the unique index, `INSERT INTO doc_perms ...` will raise an error if `(user_id, doc_id)` is a duplicate.

If you wish to INSERT, but UPDATE other columns when `(user_id, doc_id)` is a duplicate, then (as @moopet has already mentioned) you can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). For example:

```
INSERT INTO doc_perms (user_id, doc_id, foo) 
  VALUES (1, 2, 3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo = 3'''
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

See the MySQL manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html